# Javascript print blocked by chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

I'm trying to run a javascript `window.print()` from chrome. It prints the first time but then subsequent calls (within a minute of the first call) fail. The chrome log states "Ignoring too frequent calls to print()."

```
     window.print();
 setInterval(function() {
     window.print();
 }, 5000);
```

Can't find a way around this issue. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Works for me, Chrome 9. It prints each 5 seconds, I get that message though. It seems to fail when the dialog is already open by the way: http://jsfiddle.net/bBzAb/.

Comment: Why on earth would you do something like that?

Comment: I’m not, the script is merely to replicate this issue. My app contains a button to instigate 'print'

Comment: That seems like a bad decision on behalf of Google. I wonder when printing too much has actually been a problem justifying these measures.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears to be a design decision rather than a bug. Getting around it will probably be pretty hard.

Comment: Thanks, I've since added a browser-check to see if agent's chrome, a counter & a timer. If they click the button > once within a minute I've got a subtle message that appears to ask them to Ctrl+P / menu print if nothing happens.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like a deliberate choice on Chrome's part that you probably won't be able to get around.  As an alternative, you could prepare all of your jobs at once and separate them with a page break:

`<div style="page-break-after:always"></div>`

Answer (score 4):

I have found the following to be a work-around to enable JavaScript printing from Chrome:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.print(); return false;">Click me to Print</a>
```

It seems that adding the "return false" bit to the onclick handler makes Chrome happy.

I think that without it, Chrome attempts to follow the link somewhere / reload the page. This results in a print dialog showing nothing to print.

Comment: I'm not going to down-vote. But the question is about "multiple and frequent calls to window.print", not about how to enable printing. The 'return false' didn't work to prevent this behavior (Chrome v.22)

Answer (score 1):

Good!  Bug [fixed](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50186).
The bug was fixed as part of v.23 if I'm not wrong.

So if the release cycle is every 6 weeks and Chrome 22 was released 25th of Sep, then **by 6th of November** (aprox.) the fix will be in the Chrome Stable version

Answer (score 0):

In chrome you have to fire the window.location.reload event to fire a print event.. ref from  [Chrome: window.print() print dialogue opens only after page reload (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622626/chrome-window-print-print-dialogue-opens-only-after-page-reload-javascript)

This works for me..

```
window.print();
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1){
  window.location.reload();
}
```